# Behavior of a holomorphic function in unit disk near boundary

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $B(0,1)$, I need to prove there is some $z_0 \in \partial B$ and some sequence $\{z_n\} \subset B$ such that $z_n\rightarrow z_0$ and $\{f(z_n)\}$ converges.

(1) Assume $f$ doesn't vanish in $B$. To get a contradiction, uppose for any $\{z_n\} \subset B$ such that $z_n\rightarrow z_0 \in \partial B$, $\{f(z_n)\} \rightarrow \infty$. Then $\frac{1}{f}$ can be continuously extended to $\partial B$ with zero value. By maximum principle, $\frac{1}{f}$ is identically zero in $B$, contradiction.

(2) Assume $f$ has finitely many zeros $z_1,z_2,...,z_k \in B$, then $\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_k)}$ will satisfy (1).

(3) Assume $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $B$, then either $f$ is identically zero in $B$, or there is a sequence of its zeros converges to $z_0 \in \partial B$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that the radius of convergence of the power series for $f$ centered at $0$ is $1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin It's at least $1$ and if it's $>1,$ then the result is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1. All we need is a sequence $z_n$ of points in $B(0,1)$ with $|z_n| \to 1$ along which $f(z_n)$ is bounded. 2. If $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $B(0,1),$ we're done. So assume $f$ has only finitely many zeros in $B(0,1).$ Divide by an appropriate polynomial to obtain a holomorphic $g$ in $B(0,1)$ with no zeros. It's enough to prove the result for $g.$

Comment: Well, wait until you get farther along to ask that question

Comment: I have modified my post. Please check if it could be more simplified. Thank you ;)